# "Магический" квадрат матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, c++11, динамические-массивы

Написать программу которая создает "магический" квадрат. "Магический" квадрат - это матрица, в которой суммы чисел в каждом горизонтальной строке, в каждом вертикальном столбце и по диагоналям - одинакова.

по диагоналях все вышло, а вот горизонтали и вертикали - проблематично. 
помогите плиз)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
label:
    const int row = 3, col = 3;
    int arr[row][col];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int diag1 = 0, diag2 = 0, gor = 0, vert = 0, gor2=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) {
                diag1 += arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i + j == row - 1) {
                diag2 += arr[i][j];
            }

        }
    }
    //gor
    for (int l = 0; l < row; l++)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < col; v++)
        {
            gor += arr[l][v];
        }
        gor = 0;
    }
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            gor += arr[i][j];
            if ((i < row) && (j < col))
                gor2 += arr[i + 1][j + 1];
            else
                gor2 += arr[i - 1][j - 1];
    //      cout << gor << " ";
            tmp = gor;
        }
        if (tmp != gor2) {
            goto label;
        }
        gor2 = 0;
    }
    if (diag1 != diag2) {
        goto label;
    }
    cout << diag1 << " " << diag2 << endl << gor << endl;
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов запутался с вертикалями и горизонталями

Comment: матрица 3х3 именно нужна? Вот готовый пример с использованием stl

 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4952/Magic-Square

Answer (score 1):

Так вам надо проверять сгенерированные случайно или генерировать?
Если проверка - см. `check()`, если генерировать 3x3 - см. `main()` :)

```
bool check(int * arr, int size)
{
#define a(i,j) (*(arr+i*size+j))
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum1 += a(i,i);
        sum2 += a(i,size-i-1);
    }
    if (sum1 != sum2) return false;
    int sh, sv;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sv = sh = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            sv += a(j,i);
            sh += a(i,j);
        }
        if ((sv != sum1) || (sh != sum1)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int row = 3, col = 3;
    int arr[row][col];
    srand(time(nullptr));

    int a = rand()%10 + 1;
    int b = rand()%10 + 1;
    int c = rand()%10 + 1;

    arr[0][0] = a + b;
    arr[0][1] = a + 2*(b+c);
    arr[0][2] = a + c;
    arr[1][0] = a + 2*c;
    arr[1][1] = a + b + c;
    arr[1][2] = a + 2*b;
    arr[2][0] = a + 2*b + c;
    arr[2][1] = a;
    arr[2][2] = a + b + 2*c;

    for(int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {

        for(int c = 0; c < 3; ++c)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << arr[r][c];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\nIs magic: " << (check((int*)arr,3) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
}
```

Upd. Вариант поконкретнее:

```
bool check(int arr[][3])
{
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        sum1 += arr[i][i];
        sum2 += arr[i][2-i];
    }
    if (sum1 != sum2) return false;
    int sh, sv;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        sv = sh = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            sv += arr[j][i];
            sh += arr[i][j];
        }
        if ((sv != sum1) || (sh != sum1)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: мне нужно универсальную генерацию з проверкой - тоить нужно сделать так чтобы после смены количества столбцов\строк - не нужно било менять код. сейчас попробую с помощю вашего кода это реализировать. спасибо =)

Comment: @tkachuk вообще-то там универсальный код.

Comment: @pavel нувот я ставлю const int row = 4, col = 4; и все, и нужно менять код, там где генерация 3х3

Comment: @pavel и был бы очень благодарен если бы вы мне объяснили вот это: a(i,j) (*(arr+i*size+j)), а то не понимаю, да и функции еще не учил, вот в понедельник фкнкции будут

Comment: @tkachuk Ну, понимаете, многомерные массивы надо передавать с последним индексом, как `(int arr[][3])` - а это убивает универсальность. Поэтому мы просто пользуемся тем, что многомерный массив - это тот же одномерный, просто в нем строки идут подряд. Этементы 0-2 - первая строка, 3-5 - вторая и т.д. - так что `#define a(i,j) (*(arr+i*size+j))` - макрос для упрощения обращения к `[i][j]` элементу квадратного двумерного массива `arr` с размером `size`, который передается в функцию просто как указатель.

Comment: @Harry а можна этот макрос как то полностью расписать? а то я как раз его то и не понимаю, не учил еще, и эта * после первых кавычек тоже не знаю что делает

Comment: @tkachuk Это все долго объяснять, так что смотрите в ответе другой вариант, для конкретно матрицы 3x3, без фокусов...

Comment: @Harry окей. и может еще с етим поможете? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557551/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC?noredirect=1#comment722104_557551

Comment: @tkachuk Для этого вы должны внятно и понятно изложить :) Честно говорю - не все понятно...

Comment: @Harry можно использовать массивы, двухмерные массивы, цылки, нууу, все наверное, библиотеки тоже нельзя, хотя неважно, решил уже

Comment: @Harry помогите здесь еще если есть желание http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056687/search-the-local-minimum-in-martix

Answer (score 0):

сделал

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int row = 3, col = 4;
    int arr[row][col], count = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (((i - 1) < 0) && ((j - 1) < 0)) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1])){
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (((i + 1) >= row) && ((j + 1) >= col)) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i - 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1])){
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((j - 1) < 0) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i - 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j])){
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((i + 1) >= row) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i - 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1])){
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                    count++;
                }

            }
            else if ((i - 1) < 0) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j])){
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i - 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1])) {
                count++;
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            else if (((j - 1) < 0)&&((i + 1) >= row)) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j])) {
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((j + 1) >= col) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1])) {
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
            else if ((i + 1) >= row) {
                if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i - 1][j]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j - 1])){
                    count++;
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";}
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << count << endl;
}
```