# как записать числа в матрицу отдельно по эллементам?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть два массива - первый есть представление даты рождения (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ) в виде совокупности цифр, элементы второго массива получаются путем некоторых преобразований над датой рождения (вроде сложить цифры дня и месяца, затем года, и т.д.).

Пример первого массива:
{2,2,0,1,1,9,9,3}

Пример второго массива:
{3,7,6,7,5}

Нужно чтобы записалось в матрицу вида: в элемент с номером i записывается ровно столько цифр i, сколько они встретились в вышеуказанных массивах.

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

(счет идет по вертикали)
и в конечном вышло

```
11  -   77
22  5   -
33  6   99
```

типа вставка чисел в матрицу(незнаю как вставить)
если кто не понял задание - загуглите "квадрат пифагора"

вот что имеется на данный момент:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int indate = 8, dvozn=1;
    int date[indate], numb[dvozn], sum = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;
    cout << "Vvedit' datu narodzhenia v cyfrah(1 9 9 0 1 1 2 9" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < indate; i++)
    {
        cin >> date[i];
//1 number
        sum += date[i];
    }
    numb[0] = sum;
//2 number
    while (sum > 9) {
        sum = ((sum / 10) + (sum % 10));
    }
//3 number
    int tmp = 0;
    cout << date[0] << " " << date[1] << " " << ((date[0] * 10) + (date[1])) * 2 << endl;
    tmp += ((date[0] * 10) + (date[1]))*2;
    sum2 = numb[0] - tmp;
    if (sum2 < 0)
        sum2 *= -1;
    sum3 = sum2;
    while (sum3 > 9) {
        sum3 = ((sum3 / 10) + (sum3 % 10));
    }
    cout << endl << sum << " " << sum2 << " " << sum3 << endl;
//zapovnennia tablyci

    for (int i = 0; i < indate; i++)
    {
        cout << date[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    const int size5 = 5;
    int dat[size5];
    dat[0] = numb[0]/10;
    dat[1] = numb[0]%10;
    dat[2] = sum;
    dat[3] = sum2;
    dat[4] = sum3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size5; i++)
    {
        cout << dat[i] << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;

    const int size = 3;
    int arr[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

помогите пожалуйста, ну незнаю как заполнить и все. всторой день уже думаю

Comment: А что из себя должен представлять каждый элемент матрицы? Например, `11` это массив из двух единиц или число 11?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb это числа из двух первых массивов. есди бы в этих двух массивах било бы 4 еденицы то там было бы не 11, а 1111. как то так))чтото сложно объяснить))или объяснил?

Comment: `1111` это `int i = 1111;` или `std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 1, 1};`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb вот:"По своей форме это будет таблица размером 3х3 ячейки, в которую должны разместиться числа от 1 до 9. Важным окажется то, что читать таблицу надо столбиками, а не строками, как нам привычнее. То есть в первом столбце будут размещены числа 1, 2, 3 сверху вниз, во втором - 4, 5, 6 также сверху вниз, в третьем - 7, 8, 9. нулей в таблице быть не должно, поэтому их просто нужно упустить.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb  Итак, теперь в данные организации надо вставить все те цифры, которые размещены в двух найденных рядах - дата рождения и вычислены элементы. Все единицы надо внести в первую ячейку, все двойки во вторую (как описано выше, она находится второй в первом столбце) и так далее, до девятки. Если определенных цифр в составленных ранее рядах нет, ячейка просто остается пустой, можно написать слово «нет»."

Comment: Вы вообще читайте мои вопросы? Спрашиваю третий раз. Две единицы в матрице это массив из двух единиц или число одиннадцать?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb нет разницы как реализовать, главное реализовать

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, нет, не читает..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую сначала сформировать результат в виде массива, а потом преобразовать в матрицу. Это проще всего сделать используя `std::valarray`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>

template<class Iterator>
void fill(Iterator begin, Iterator end, std::valarray<int> &result){
    for(;begin != end; ++begin){
        result[*begin] = result[*begin] * 10 + *begin;
    }
}

int main(){
    //Исходные данные
    std::vector<int> v1 = {2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 3};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {3, 7, 6, 7, 5};

    //Результат ввиде массива
    std::valarray<int> result(10);

    //Формируем массив
    fill(v1.begin(), v1.end(), result);
    fill(v2.begin(), v2.end(), result);

    //Преобразуем массив в матрицу
    std::valarray<std::valarray<int>> matrix(std::valarray<int>(3), 3);
    for(int i =  0; i < 3; ++i){
        std::slice slice(i + 1, 3, 3);
        matrix[i] = result[slice];    
    }

    //Вывод матрицы на экран
    for(const std::valarray<int> &line : matrix){
        for(int i : line){
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

http://cpp.sh/6pwt

**UPD** Вариант без использования стандартной библиотеки, функций, шаблонов и всего прочего

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    //Исходные данные
    int v1[] = {2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 3};
    int v2[] = {3, 7, 6, 7, 5};

    //Результат ввиде массива
    int result[10] = {0};

    //Формируем массив
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(v1)/sizeof(int); ++i){
        int number = v1[i];
        result[number] = result[number] * 10 + number;
    }
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(v2)/sizeof(int); ++i){
        int number = v2[i];
        result[number] = result[number] * 10 + number;
    }

    //Преобразуем массив в матрицу
    int matrix[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            matrix[i][j] = result[i + 1 + 3 * j];
        }
    }

    //Печатаем матрицу
    std::cout << std::setw(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            int number = matrix[i][j];
            if(number > 0){
                std::cout <<  number << " ";
            }
            else{
                std::cout <<  "- ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: без функций нужно(

Comment: Видимо, и без шаблонов, тем более, да ?

Comment: @tkachuk, ну вставьте код функции вместо вызова

Comment: @isnullxbh не понимаю о чем вы, но наверное да

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb и без вектора

Comment: @tkachuk, во-первых об этом стоило написать сразу в вопросе. Во-вторых, когда вы уже начнете пользоваться хотя бы функциями? Я уже не первый раз вижу ваши вопросы, и постоянно вы от них отказываетесь. В-третьих, добавил  ответ версию без функций и стандартной библиотеки

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb с понедельника начну функции xD

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb такая учебная программа. но очень много задают, ооочень, все не получается сделать

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb посмотрите еще здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557639/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    const int resLength = 9;
    const int numLength = 8;
    // это для массива 2 - я взял 5 просто так, сами определите
    const int appLength = 5;

    int resArr[resLength] = { 0 };
    int numArr[numLength] = { 0 };
    // ПОВТОРЯЮ - второй массив проинициализировал сам
    // Вы же сделаете нужные вам расчеты, и получите элементы для него
    const int appArr[appLength] = { 2,2,4,5,5 };

    std::string birthDateAsStr;

    std::cout << "\nВведите дату Вашего рождения: ";
    std::cin >> birthDateAsStr;

    // из строки в массив 
    int count = 0;
    const char * ptr = birthDateAsStr.c_str();
    for (int i = 0; i < birthDateAsStr.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(birthDateAsStr[i]))
        {
            // не красиво, но работает (
            const char c = birthDateAsStr[i];
            numArr[count++] = atoi(&c);
        }
    }

    // вывожу в линейный, но соответствие "цифре I ячейка I" - сохраняется.
    // для 1
    for (int i = 0; i < numLength; ++i)
    {
        if (numArr[i] == 0) continue;

        resArr[numArr[i] - 1] *= 10;
        resArr[numArr[i] - 1] += numArr[i];
    }

    // для 2
    for (int i = 0; i < appLength; ++i)
    {
        if (numArr[i] == 0) continue;

        resArr[appArr[i] - 1] *= 10;
        resArr[appArr[i] - 1] += appArr[i];
    }

    // а вот вывожу уже как 1 4 7
    //                      2 5 8
    //                      3 6 9

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << resArr[i] << "  " << resArr[i + 3] << "  " << resArr[i + 6] << std::endl;
    }
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```