# Найти индекс строки которая имеет наибольшее число повторяющихся элементов(работает, но неадекватно)

Tags: c++, c, массивы, arraylist, динамические-массивы

Не адекватно работает, хотя по логике, вроде бы, все норм:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int row = 4, col = 4;
    int arr[row][col];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    /*arr[3][0] = 1;
    arr[3][1] = 1;
    arr[3][2] = 1;
    arr[3][3] = 1;
    arr[3][4] = 1;*/
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int index = 0, count = 0, tmp = 0, num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            num = arr[i][j];

            for (int z = 0; z < row; z++) { //здесь перебор и сравнение
                tmp = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
                {
                    if (arr[z][x] == num) {
                        if ((i != z) && (j != x)) {
                            tmp++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (tmp > 0) {
                        if (tmp >= count) {
                            index = z;
                            count = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << index<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без использования контейнеров это, фактически, будет код на чистом С. Единственное отличие, использование `new`, а не `malloc`.
Самая нетривиальная часть задачи - найти "наибольшее число повторяющихся элементов в строке". Если имеется в виду, что в строке `1, 2, 1, 2, 1` это число 3 (3 единицы), решение этой задачи просто требует выделения в отдельную функцию.
Эта функция может выглядеть так:

```
size_t count_els(size_t size, int row[]) {
    if (!row || !size) return 0;
    int *elements = new int[size];      // массив уникальных элементов в row
    size_t *counter = new size_t[size]; // массив счетчиков количества элементов
    if (!elements || !counter) {
        cout << "cannot allocate memory";
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) counter[i] = 0; // его нужно обнулить
    size_t current_index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int element = row[i];
        // find element in elements[0:current_index]
        bool need_to_add = true;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < current_index; ++j) {
            // Проверка counter[j]!=0 должна стоять первой!
            if (counter[j] != 0 && elements[j] == element) { // нашли
                need_to_add = false; // добавлять не нужно
                counter[j]++;
                break; // т.к. элементы уникальные, дальше искать не нужно
            }
        }
        if (need_to_add) { // элемент row[i] не найден в массиве elements, добавляем
            elements[current_index] = element;
            counter[current_index] = 1;
            ++current_index;
        }
    }
    // Теперь находим максимальный элемент в массиве counter
    size_t max_counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < current_index; ++i) {
        if (counter[i] > max_counter)
            max_counter = counter[i];
    }
    delete[] counter;
    delete[] elements;
    return max_counter;
}
```

Фактически, нам нужно посчитать количество всех уникальных элементов в строке, и найти максимальное. Для этого (имхо) не обойтись без двух дополнительных массивов (уникальные элементы `elements` и счетчик их количества `counter`). Их размер не может превышать длину строки. В принципе, ничто не мешает, весь этот код написать непосредственно в `main`, но выглядеть это будет ужасно коряво.

С этой функцией, `main` (после заполнения исходного двумерного массива `m` размером `rows x cols`) может выглядеть так:

```
size_t needed_row = 0, longest = 0;
for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
   current = count_els(cols, m[row])
   if (current > longest) {
      longest = current;
      needed_row = row;
   }
}
cout << "needed row index is " << needed_row << endl;
```

Если Ваш преподаватель будет возражать против отдельной функции, спорьте. Если он не дурак, поймет, что она здесь нужна. Ну, а если дурак, тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

---

Код с использование контейнеров стандартной библиотеки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
size_t maxcounted_element(const vector<T> &v) {
    // Найти наибольшее число повторяющихся элементов в векторе
    vector<pair<size_t, T>> t;
    t.reserve(v.size());
    for (const T& el: v) {
        bool to_push = true;
        for (size_t i=0; i<t.size(); ++i) {
            if (t.at(i).second == el) {
                ++t.at(i).first;
                to_push = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (to_push) {
            t.push_back({1, el});
        }
    }
    size_t maxs = 0;
    for (auto &e: t) {
        if (e.first > maxs) maxs = e.first;
    }
    return maxs;
}

template<typename T>
size_t find_row(size_t size, const vector<T> m[]) {
    // найти строку с наибольшим количеством повторяющихся элементов
    if (!m || !size) return 0;
    size_t longest = 0;
    size_t index = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        size_t current = maxcounted_element(m[i]);
        if (current > longest) {
            longest = current;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> m[] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 1, 1, 4, 5},
        {1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 2, 2, 2},
        {},
        {1.23, 1.23, 3.14}
    };
    size_t row = find_row(5, m);
    cout << "Row number " << row
         << " contains " << maxcounted_element(m[row]) << " equals elements" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Row number 2 contains 4 equals elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем городить такую мешанину? И самого путает, и другим в этой груде буковок разбираться не интересно. Проще и эффективней разбить код на подзадачи, отладить каждую из них отдельно, и только после этого собирать в единое целое. Начать можно с малого: с написания функции, которая находит самую длинную последовательность в одном массиве. Например, набрасываю на коленке:

```
size_t longest_int_chain( const int *data, size_t size )
{
    size_t longest = 1; /* максимальная цепочка */
    size_t current = 1; /* длина текущей цепочки */
    int c;              /* текущее значение */
    size_t i = 0;

    /* параноиком быть не вредно */
    if( !data || !size ) {
        return 0;
    }

    c = data[0];
    while( ++i < size ) {
        if( data[i] == c ) {
            current++;
        }
        else {
            if( current > longest ) {
                longest = current;
            }
            c = data[i];
            current = 1;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

И вот когда эта функция будет отлажена и начнёт гарантированно выдавать правильный результат - проходимся ей по массивам в поисках максимального значения.

Comment: Ваша функция находит самую длинную последовательность, а в задаче - наибольшее число повторяющихся элементов. Например `{1,2,1,2,1,3,4,5}` - самая длинная последовательность = 1, а число повторяющихся элементов = 3 (3 единицы).

Comment: А, точно :) Но принцип и подход от этого не меняется.

Comment: @andy.37 без функций, без векторов, без шаблонов, без ничего нужно)

Comment: @gottar  без функций, без векторов, без шаблонов, без ничего нужно)

Comment: @tkachuk дополнил ответ